# Covariant Derivative of Matrix Times Vector

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Good evening!

I was wondering if one could prove some sort of "product rule" for the covariant derivative by using parallel transport: Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, then it is known that a connection $\nabla$ is uniquely characterized by its parallel transport via $$(\nabla_\xi X)_x = \left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0} P^\gamma_{t,0}(X(\gamma(t))) = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{P_{t,0}^\gamma (X(\gamma(t))) - X(x)}{t},$$
where $P_{t,0}^\gamma$ denotes the (reverse) parallel transport of a vector field $X\in \Gamma TM$ along the geodesic $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow M$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\dot\gamma(0)=\xi$ for a $\xi\in T_x M$, $x\in M$.

Now, for a $J\in \Gamma\operatorname{End}(TM)$, my idea was to insert a useful zero like in the proof of the regular product rule:
\begin{align*}(\nabla_\xi JX)_x &= \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{P_{t,0}^\gamma (J(\gamma(t))X(\gamma(t))) - J(x)X(x)}{t}\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{P_{t,0}^\gamma (J(\gamma(t))X(\gamma(t))) - J(x)P_{t,0}^\gamma(X(\gamma(t)))+J(x)P_{t,0}^\gamma(X(\gamma(t))) -J(x)X(x)}{t}\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{[P_{t,0}^\gamma (J(\gamma(t))X(\gamma(t))) - J(x)P_{t,0}^\gamma(X(\gamma(t)))]+J(x)[P_{t,0}^\gamma(X(\gamma(t))) -X(x)]}{t}\\
&= \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{[P_{t,0}^\gamma (J(\gamma(t))X(\gamma(t))) - J(x)P_{t,0}^\gamma(X(\gamma(t)))]}{t}+J(x)(\nabla_\xi X)(x)
\end{align*}
However, even though the right term is exactly what one wants, I don't see how the term on the left can be brought into the form $$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{[P_{t,0}^\gamma (J(\gamma(t))) - J(x)]}{t}X(x) = (\nabla_\xi J)_x X(x).$$
So, was my idea just useless? Or does anyone see a way to save this attempt?

Comment: The issue is this: Is $P(JX) = P(J)P(X)$ (all annotations to be added)?

Comment: How are you defining the parallel transport of $J$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Good question. I think the most natural thing would be to define $$P_{t,0}^\gamma J(\gamma(t)) := P_{t,0}^\gamma\circ J(\gamma(t))\circ P_{0,t}^\gamma,$$
however I am not sure whether or not the covariant derivative induced by this concept of parallel transport coincides with the one for $J$ as a $(0,2)$-tensor

Comment: $(0,2)$-tensor? How is that?

Comment: @TedShifrin My bad, $(1,1)$-tensor of course

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative  directly above and below the end of "Motivation".   I presume you know about the covariant derivative expansion of (i,k;j) and then contraction j=k.   If I was taking your approach, I would follow the "Chris Hillman" approach (below), starting with the Lie derivative and working up to the situation you have.  Possibly I am misreading the problem, though.
Chris Hillman

Reference: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/lie-vs-covariant-derivative.150200/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case someone else might have the same question: The product rule I was looking for holds and takes the form $$\nabla (JX) = J(\nabla X) + (\nabla J)X.$$

It follows immediately  from the Leibniz formula for tensor products in the case of vector valued $1$-forms, or can be calculated within the "usual" setup using local bases:

**Proof**

Let $J\in\Gamma\operatorname{End}(TM)$ be a linear map, as well as $(e_1,...,e_n)$ a local basis and $(dx_1,....,dx_n)$ the corresponding dual basis, i.e. $dx_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

Then firstly, $J$ can be seen as the $(1,1)$-tensor $J=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i\otimes Je_i$. By the Leibniz rule for tensor products, this means
\begin{equation}\tag{1} \nabla J  =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \nabla dx_i \otimes J e_i + dx_i\otimes \nabla Je_i.\end{equation}

Any $X\in\Gamma TM$ can be locally written as $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i(X) e_i$, so $(1)$ can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}\tag{2} (\nabla J)X  =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\nabla dx_i)(X) J e_i + dx_i(X) \nabla Je_i.\end{equation}

Also, we can write $JX = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i(X) Je_i$
and can calculate (using again the Leibniz rule) \begin{equation}\tag{3} \nabla (JX) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \nabla (dx_i(X)) Je_i+dx_i(X)\nabla  Je_i.\end{equation}

By definition, $$(\nabla dx_i)(X) := \nabla (dx_i(X)) - dx_i(\nabla_{\bullet} X),$$ so subtracting $(2)$ from $(3)$ leaves us with \begin{equation}\tag{4} \nabla(JX)-(\nabla J)X = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i(\nabla_\bullet X)Je_i.\end{equation}
But the right hand side of $(4)$ is precisely $J(\nabla X)$, since   $\nabla_\bullet  X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i(\nabla_\bullet X)e_i$ and so \begin{equation}J(\nabla_{\bullet} X) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n dx_i(\nabla_{\bullet} X)Je_i.\end{equation}